# How do you create a constant from readFile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

So i wanna write a bot for Telegram and I just want to get the token (the secret to authorize the bot) out of a .txt file, so that I dont accidentally push the secret onto my repo.

I've tried this before:

```
const token = fileReader.readFile('BOT_CREDENTIALS.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
    return data.toString();
});

console.log(token);
```

The first console.log actually returns the token from the file, but the second one just returns "undefinded".

So therefore I have the question on how do I get the token from that file as a constant that I can use later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your fileReader variable is probably the [Node fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

[readfile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) is an asynchronous function. Reading a file, just like sending an HTTP request, takes time, what is happening in your code:

1. The request function is executed, passing an anonymous function as a callback to execute when a response is available sometime in the future.
2. Your second console.log is immediately output to the console.
3. Sometime in the future, the response comes back and our callback is executed, outputting its body to the console

In asynchronous programs, you can have two lines of code (L1 followed by L2), where L1 schedules some task to be run in the future, but L2 runs before that task completes.
In synchronous programs, if you have two lines of code (L1 followed by L2), then L2 cannot begin running until L1 has finished executing.

NodeJS/Javascript is asynchronous.

If you wish to read the file and store it synchronously, you can use the [readfileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) function, your code would look like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const token = fs.readFileSync('BOT_CREDENTIALS.txt')
console.log(token.toString())
```

Be aware that this is a blocking operation, therefore, nothing below the readfile will execute until the file is done being read, this includes the whole Event Loop thread.

As for your concern about committing your credentials, you could use environment variables, it's a well documented and widespread practice.
One good option is the [dotenv module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure
>   dotenv.
>
> `require('dotenv').config()` 
>   Create a .env file in the root directory of
>   your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the
>   form of NAME=VALUE.

In your case, you would use it like this:

```
.env file
TOKEN=SOMETHING

Javascript file
const token = process.ENV.TOKEN
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what i needed! The dotenv worked perfectly for me.
Thank you for your time to help me :)